# duplicate entries on datagridview

Tags: datagridview, multiple-entries

I'd like to find duplicated entries one of the columns on datagridview. After that I need to send an email to users for arrange collection for those duplicated numbers. It doesnt matter how many duplicated numbers we have on column so i dont want to count them, i just need to know all those duplicated numbers itself on column.. I have sorted e-mail already, but i couldnt figure out how i can easily find duplicated entries.

[image]

attached a screen shot here, for example on this screen shot i already have four 0's on column, it needs to tell me that " I have duplicated 0 on sending_location" .

Datagridview taking information from MS Access Datasource.

I am using visual studio.

Many thanks!
Charlie

Comment: What about framework? Need more info in the question.

Comment: Hello Jacek, I am sorry to not mention of framework here, as you can tell i am newbie and trying my best to learn. it is running .net framework 4.5.2 formapp

Answer (score 0):

If the datagridview is bound to a datasource, is it not easy to find out at the query level or during the databinding event.

Comment: Basically i have created ms access, and i have linked access to datagridview. users are not touching ms access, they are adding,saving, deleting entries from programme... Would you have any advise for me in order to find those duplicated entries? Manythanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EntityFramework

```
//resultset is the result from the query that return all data
var duplicates = resultset
                     .GroupBy(i => i.ColumnName)
                     .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                     .Select();
```

if using datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));

        //populate table
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "David", "New York");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Emma","Albany");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Michael", "Chicago");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Jennifer", "Chicago");
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "Steve", "Albany");

        var duplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("City"))
                       .Select(g => g.First())
                       .CopyToDataTable();
```

duplicates will have unique duplicated rows